# match regex to remove password from file

Tags: regex, linux, sed

I have a file which contain following lines

```
app.mail.host = 10.1.1.1
app.mail.debug = true
app.db.username = spate
app.db.password = 1#4FnL&@7!
```

I want to use regex to change actual password and replace with XXXXXXX for security purpose.

I am trying following regex but it doesn't working.

```
sed 's/app\.db\.password="[^"]\+/app\.db\.password="XXXXXXXX"/g' foo.txt
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Hbcdev noted, you aren't matching due to whitespace.  As this appears to be "security" code (in which case -- why are you storing that password in plaintext at all?), it's probably better to be whitespace-tolerant than match the input byte-for-byte.  Something like:

```
sed 's/app\.db\.password[ \t]*=.*/app.db.password="xxxxx"/
```

(untested) is probably going to work a little more robustly.  Note that it will strip your password field even if it doesn't begin with a quote.

Still, doing this kind of hackery with a shell script sounds dangerous.  What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: interesting this is also work  sed 's/app\.db\.password.*/app\.db\.password="XXXXXXXX"/g'

Comment: Yes, but that will match a field like "app.db.password_hex" or the like, which may not be what you want.  Really, this isn't something you should be doing in shell if you really want to hide secret information.

Comment: This is not super secret password but just wanted to hide when we doing file backup process to remote server.

Answer (score 2):

You haven't left spaces around the `=` sign in your `sed` expression. Once you do that I think it'll work.